# Huawei G700 keeps asking permission to use mobile data after WiFi disconnects

Tags: wi-fi, mobile-data, huawei-g700

I recently bought a Huawei G700. It's a fairly new and uncommon device. It runs Android 4.2.1 in combination with Huawei's own Emotion UI

When I have WiFi enabled and for some reason my Wifi disconnects (for example I go out of reach), my phone keeps asking me, each and every time, if it's allowed to use Mobile Data. if I don't answer, my mobile data does not connect thus I can't recieve any mails etc which is highly annoying.

This is the exact error/popup message that I get:

> Data connection change 
>   WLAN is unavailable, try to connect to mobile network?

I've googled this exact phrase, but I get 0 results.
 How can I prevent my phone from asking if it's allowed to use mobile data?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this behavior is present in all recent Chinese ROMs from Huawei and there is no way to disable it. However, I found a workaround for it; The message only popsup if you have WiFi and Data Enabled and you lose WiFi connectivity. Then your phone will ask if it's allowed to switch from WiFi to Data. So, if you make sure WiFi is disabled before switching to Data, it will not ask this question. To do so manually, takes a lot of time. Luckily there is an app that can automate this task for you. Here's how:

Install the app 'Llama' from the Market (Free) and create these two events:

[image]

The 1 second delay is necessary, else it does not work properly.

What it does: Switch off WiFi as soon WiFi disconnects from your WiFi network and then enables Data. This way, it does not show the popup and 'automatically' switch to Data. Don't forget to manually enable WiFi again if you are in reach again of your WiFi network.
If you want Llama to automatically turn back WiFi on as soon you get home/in reach of your WiFi, you have to let it learn your location. Read the help/documentention on how to do so. It's pretty easy to do :)

This 'fix' works for me 9 out 10 times. Give it a try, I hope it helps you.